# wireless camera options

Tags: recommendations, video-transmitters, fpv-cameras

I know drones use high fps and long range cameras, I'm working on a tracked robot and quality is a higher concern then fps per say. I have found boards that allow multi camera options but I was hoping for suggestions from folks who build and use them on a regular basis. I'm using a **12v** system and an **fs-i6X 10channel** with an **Arduino** to run all my servos and motors.

here is what i was looking at

3-way multi channel board
https://www.getfpv.com/lumenier-3-way-video-switcher-board.html

main camera **runcamera phoenix2**
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B084FSDY5D/ref=ox_sc_saved_title_1?smid=A1CA0481MF6RWW&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084FSDY5D)

and a **ts/tc832** wireless system. I've looked into ip stuff but it seams a lot more complicated then im trying to do.

Comment: As far as I know, almost all decent analog FPV cameras will have little-to-no variation in resolution. It's just a limitation of the analog transmitting technology. If you're purely after higher quality, digital systems might be more suitable.